# Programmatically build an F# regular expression with the FsVerbalExpressions library

Tags: regex, f#

I've been using the library [FsVerbalExpressions](http://verbalexpressions.github.io/FSharpVerbalExpressions/) to write some functions.  I'm having a hard time trying to build a regEx programmatically.

For example, if I have a string `"Int. Bus. Mach"`, I can remove periods and whitespaces and end up with the array

```
let splitString = [|"Int"; "Bus"; "Mach"|]
```

What I'd like to do is build a regular expression from `splitString` so that its result is:

```
let hardCoded = 
    VerbEx()
    |> startOfLine
    |> then' "Int"
    |> anything
    |> whiteSpace
    |> then' "Bus"
    |> anything
    |> whiteSpace
    |> then' "Mach"

hardCoded;;
val it : VerbEx =
  ^(Int)(.*)\s(Bus)(.*)\s(Mach) {MatchTimeout = -00:00:00.0010000;
                                 Regex = ^(Int)(.*)\s(Bus)(.*)\s(Mach);
                                 RegexOptions = None;
                                 RightToLeft = false;}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to build this programmatically so that, if the original string is `"This is a much bigger string"`, the entire regEx is built from code rather than hard coded.  I can create individual regular expressions with

```
        let test = 
            splitString
            |> Array.map (fun thing -> VerbEx()
                                        |> then' thing)
            |> Array.toList
```

but this is a list of `VerbEx()` rather than a single `VerbEx()` above.

Does anyone know how I could build a regEx with `FsVerbalExpressions` programmatically?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about it like this: you need to start with some initial value, `VerbEx() |> startOfLine`, and then apply to it repeating patterns that have the general shape of `anything |> whitespace |> then' word`.

You can also think about it in inductive terms: you're producing a series of values, where each value is expressed as `previousValue |> anything |> whitespace |> then' word` - that is, each next value in the series is previous value with some change applied to it. The very last element of such series is your final answer.

Such operation - producing a series of values, where each value is expressed as a modification of the previous one, - is traditionally called `fold`. And sure enough, F# has standard library functions for performing this operation:

```
let applyChange previousValue word = 
  previousValue |> anything |> whitespace |> then' word

let initialValue = VerbEx() |> startOfLine

let finalAnswer = splitString |> Array.fold applyChange initialValue
```

Or you can roll that all together:

```
let finalAnswer = 
  splitString 
  |> Array.fold 
       (fun previousValue word -> previousValue |> anything |> whitespace |> then' word)
       (VerbEx() |> startOfLine)
```

Comment: I'm moderately new to `F#` and *definitely* new writing folds.  This is *very* helpful.  THANKS!

Comment: You can make this even a little bit shorter. Fold the other way round to enable eta-reduction: `VerbEx() |> startOfLine |> Array.foldBack (fun word -> anything >> whiteSpace >> then' word) [|"Mach"; "Bus"; "Int"|]`

Comment: @kaefer: this would really defeat the point of approachable explanation, and doesn't provide any real benefit.